# Using fish shell function within a script

Tags: linux, shell, docker, debian, fish

I have a bunch of shell scripts, the first being one which installs the popular Fish shell. Once this step completes I copy a `functions/` directory to the appropriate location. I then want to use the `spin` function to call each shell script and display a spinner, while each script is executing. However after I get passed the initial installation of Fish and configuration I am unable to use the functions i.e. `spin <command>` results in `command not found`.

**NOTE** This is happening within an ephemeral docker container for testing.

Any pointers or help with this, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with `fish` but typically, shell functions are not available in noninteractive shells. A simple and straightforward workaround is to change the implementation from a function to a regular external command.

Comment: @tripleee Functions are available in non-interactive shells though the files that define them may not be loaded by those shells. Aliases, on the other hand, are often not available in non-interactive shells.

Comment: For fish, this should actually work because it always sources the same files. That is unless you explicitly guarded it with `if status --is-interactive`. Is that functions directory in your `$fish_function_path`?

Comment: It is and there are no guards in place, for the sake of debugging. It's an unusual situation.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/completion/fish/docker.fish

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriate location"? Is it a directory in the list `$fish_function_path`? Are you perhaps accidentally creating a *.../functions/functions/* structure with your copy?

Comment: The appropriate location is `/home/{username}/.config/fish/functions`, the initial copy happens once and is not done so through a loop, so there is no `functions/functions` directory. Before the script exits, a simple `ls` of the `.config/fish` directory confirms that there is only one occurrence of `functions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run fish functions from outside fish, use `fish -c` with a fish command line as one string.

For example, this fails...

```
env __fish_pwd
```

...but this works:

```
env fish -c __fish_pwd
```

This is because `env` runs executables, not fish functions. I assume `spin` is like this too.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems to work with everything except spin which comes from the fisherman plugin manager, perhaps there is an issue there. Functions within there directory are indeed available from bash using the technique you described. Thanks for that. Any info or resource for `env` running executables? I see `#!/usr/bin/env <int>` alot in scripts, I guess that's why.